# Rich e-book authoring, other than iBooks Author?

Tags: kindle, creation, apple-books

i am writing (or should i say, developing) an ebook on iBooks Author with all the cool features it provides. After this I wanted to do a version of it for other platforms, such as the Kindle. From what I know, there is no way of creating a book that has the ability to receive user interaction (eg a quiz or that kind of thing).

Do any of you know any form of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is not entirely true. I have made some ePub3 eBooks with user interaction back in 2013. You can use JavaScript to do the job. Problem was than there are wasn't many readers which could use it. Now we have readium and ADE4 with ePub3 so things may be different. Still it was for ePub3 not kindle eBooks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I do know that it's not entirely true, it was to simplify the question, i also know how to make a book for kindle with links from one place of the book to another and could do a quiz that way, but it's just not what i was looking for. I was wondering if anyone knew more about this kind of thing, i have 0 experience with authoring a book for kindle and i could be just ignorant about the latest tools. Thanks

Comment: It is not possible for kindle at this time because Amazon block any of JavaScript.